# How to create an effective landing page easily to capture visitor data

Tags: content-management-system, analytics

We have a CMS based website where we provide the visitors details about our company and the services we offer. But sadly we don't have ways to capture the details of the people who are visiting our site and hence we are losing vital LEADS.

Will like to know if there is any TOOL/TECHNIQUE (preferably FREE and very easy to set up) that I can use to design a simple yet effective landing page for my site.

In case you know of any code which can simply be plugged into our CMS to create a landing page that will be great as we have medium knowledge about coding.

Comment: What do you mean by "capture the details of the people who are visiting our site"?

Comment: Lead = contact info, I guess: phone, email, ...

Comment: It depends on the service your site offers/provides and what information you want to collect. If it's contact information, then hopefully you're offering a service that could plausibly require those details.

Comment: @nmichaels thanks for pointing that out. Is it possible for you to share with me how I can accept an answer? The site is built using ucms @Eli i will like to have a some sort of form with call to action like say request a free quote or FREE trail where they can key-in their contact details and thus we can followup on that lead, discuss about our service and then hopefully convert few of those leads

Comment: @beginning_steps: Pick an answer you like to a question you've asked. There should be a check mark next to it, under the vote buttons. Click it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a landing page, just use some web analytics software.
http://piwik.org/ is quite good and free/open-souce.

Comment: i need to get their email and contact numbers so that i can follow-up with them, discuss about the services we offer and hopefully convert few of these visitors in paying customers

Answer (score 0):

First you have to ask yourself why would your visitors want to leave their info.
One solution is to propose some newsletter registration.

Comment: yes exactly we are offering 2 weeks free trail for our services and will like the visitors to fill a form to avail/try out our services

Comment: Then you have to promote this on your homepage and link this action to some registration form. I'm pretty sure your CMS will allow you to create such a page.